# How exactly should I host a dart package internally in an internet less environment

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web, flutter-packages

I am trying to host all the packages my flutter application depends in svn repo and use it in a system without internet connection(unfortunately git is not possible yet) but has access to this svn repo.

**What I did so far:**

I do know I can use a path based dependency in my `pubspec.yaml` by using the `path` attribute. For e.g.

I can depend on a specific package named `xyz` by keeping it along with its dependecies in a folder say `packages` alongside the `lib` folder as shown below.

```
project
 |_ lib
 |_ packages
   |_ xyz
   |_ dep1_for_xyz
   |_ dep2_for_xyz
```

Then referring to it in `pubspec.yaml` as shown below and this works.

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  xyz:
    path: packages/xyz
```

**Problems & question:**
I came across this environment variable `pub_hosted_url` in the following pages: [ref1](https://dart.dev/tools/pub/dependencies#hosted-packages) and [ref2](https://dart.dev/tools/pub/environment-variables).

I tried to use it as follows.

1. Create an environment variable `pub_hosted_url` and point it to a directory in the remote svn repo.

   - for e.g., `https://username:password@repository_url/dart_packages`.
2. Then add & commit a package inside this `dart_packages` folder.

   - for e.g. `built_value_generator-6.8.2` and all its relevant dependencies in a similar fashion.
3. Then add the dependencies in the `pubspec.yaml` as usual.

   - for e.g `built_value_generator: ^6.7.1`
4. Then run the `flutter pub get -v`.

***Problem1***:
I am currently facing an Handshake error on client side. I understand this because of the certificate that svn server uses. Since its a self signed certificate,  flutter/pub/dart is unable to verify the validity of this certificate.

following is the error I see.

```
[ +528 ms] IO  : Retry #1 for GET https://pub_hosted_url/api/packages/built_value_generator...
[   +3 ms] IO  : HTTP GET https://pub_hosted_url/api/packages/built_value_generator
[   +2 ms]     | Accept: application/vnd.pub.v2+json
[   +2 ms]     | user-agent: Dart pub 2.7.0
[  +24 ms] IO  : HTTP error:
[   +2 ms]     | HandshakeException: Handshake error in client (OS Error:
[   +2 ms]     |        CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED: self signed certificate in certificate chain(handshake.cc:354))
[   +1 ms]     |
[   +1 ms]     | dart:_http                                         _HttpClient.openUrl
[   +2 ms]     | package:http/src/io_client.dart 33:36              IOClient.send
[        ]     | package:pub/src/http.dart 68:39                    _PubHttpClient.send
[        ]     | package:http_retry/http_retry.dart 97:33           RetryClient.send
```

***Question1***
How do I let `flutter pub get` know that this is a trusted host or even add this certificate into its trusted list.

***Problem 2:***
This problem I see is from the above error message, where the packages are looked with the following url format `https://pub_hosted_url/api/packages/my_dependency`. This means the `flutter pub get` expects packages to be placed in a very specific format or specific location. I couldn't find any relevant documentation for this apart from this alpha level `pub_server` package [here](https://github.com/dart-lang/pub_server).

***Question 2***
So question is What is the correct format of hosting our packages internally in an svn repo, if at all if its possible.

Comment: You'll likely have more success by writing an issue

Comment: @RémiRousselet so glad to hear from you :-) . I will try to post an issue, but I am not exactly sure if that would be a duplicate of this [issue](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/32131) which looks similar but only talks about the certificate related trouble.

Comment: @AbhilashChandran did find any solution I am facing the same conundrum.